# TFS 2015 Build number in YY_week number_ day number format

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I started creating TFS 2015 build ( vNext) definition file. For build number format currently I have

```
$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)_$(Rev:r)
```

It gives as `BuildName_2016.05.28_1`

> But, I wanted $(BuildDefinitionName)*$(Year:yy).**Week number.Day
>   Number***$(Rev:r)
>
> In real for example  :  **BuildName_16.21.6_1**

Anyway I can achieve this **Week number** and Day number? So that I can use the same format for releases and version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately， there is no `$（Week）`variables  just like `$(Month)` to use directly, so you have to add a custom variables to achieve weekly by yourself.

[image]

You may have to manually edit the value of week or write a PS script to achieve this. More details about how to manage Version Numbers, please refer this [blog](https://blogs.incyclesoftware.com/2015/06/vnext-build-awesomeness-managing-version-numbers/).

Comment: yes, i noticed. Looks like its the only option to have have $（Week） variable.  but have to give the values every time manually while queuing the build. if i set up the CI build, i wonder how it works.